# Hide a button in MS Access Report based on textbox value

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hi I have a form which contains a sub-report in it. Subreport contains month-wise list with buttons which export data from access db to excel. I am trying to hide the buttons in the report if the month field in the access db are empty. I have tried the code below but the button still appears in the report. The button is getting hidden when i focus on the report but not on loading. Any suggestions?

```
Private Sub Report_Current()
   If IsNull(Me!RcvdMnth) Then
       Me.btnExport.Visible = False
   Else
       Me!btnExport.Visible = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try the Private Sub Report_Load() Method?

Comment: @asdev: Yes i have tried using Report_Load() menthod and i get the same result. I have also tried IsEmpty but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

try using the same code on the on load event.

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
   If IsNull(Me!RcvdMnth) Then
       Me.btnExport.Visible = False
   Else
       Me!btnExport.Visible = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried using Report_Load() menthod and i get the same result. Is there any other method where i can get it done. I can see that the 'RcvdMnth'  field is empty, but the visible property is not being applied.

Comment: instead of using `Me.btnExport.Visible` try `formname.reportname.btnExport.Visible`. the same for `Me.RcvdMnth` try the full path i.e specifying the form & report name

Comment: Thank you for the support. ive tried all the methods suggested and with some changes as well. its working in a subreport of a report but not working in the subreport of a form.

Comment: i have recreated the situation & it works fine, email me your sample db thebenionway@gmail.com & i 'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Report_Current()
    If IsEmpty(Me!RcvdMnth) Or IsNull(Me!RcvdMnth) Then
        Me.btnExport.Visible = False
    Else
        Me.btnExport.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried to recreate a form and subreport based on your description and it worked for me.

Comment: I have tried the same but still same result. Its getting hidden when i focus on the report else it stays the same. Ive also tried .requery on Load but no effect. Thank you for support.

Comment: You are right. It does not work, sorry. You could use the code on the click button object, with a message Box if RcvdMnth is empty

Comment: Well that was the only solution i could find. I had to use a MsgBox prompting "No Records". Thank You for helping asdev.